# Change background color of a single mat-card in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, frontend

This is the HTML code of my mat-card list in my Angular application:

```
<div [ngClass]="verticalResultsBarStyle">
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <mat-card [ngClass]="barStyle" *ngFor="let card of obs | async | paginate: { id: 'paginator', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: currentPage, totalItems: totalItems }" (click)="highlightCard()">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{card[0].title}}</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>{{card[0].subtitle}}</mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>{{card[0].info1}}</p>
        <p>{{card[0].info2}}</p>
        <p>{{card[0].info3}}</p>
        <p>{{card[0].info4}}</p>
        <p>{{card[0].info5}}</p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="OnPaginateChange($event)" id="paginator"></pagination-controls>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the CSS:

```
.verticalResultsBarContainerEnabled {

  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 16%;
  float: right;
  overflow: visible;

}

.verticalResultsBarContainerDisabled {
  display: none;
}

.card {

  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.cardHighlight {

  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #c12400;
  color: white;
}

.innerDiv {
  height: 755px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.paginator {
  margin: auto;
  width: 92%;
}
```

and finally this is a snippet of TS :

```
highlightCard() {
    if (this.barStyle === 'card') {
      this.barStyle = 'cardHighlight';
    } else {
      this.barStyle = 'card';
    }
  }
```

I would to click on a single mat card and highlight only the selected mat card, but when I click on a single card, the entire list changes color. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use index for each of your cards. Your issue is normal.

I see **barStyle** is one generall for all your cards. You need to update barStyle for each card, when your cards come from backend.

First, in your .ts :

```
service.subscribe(cards => {
let i = 0
cards.forEach(card => {
  this.barStyle[i] = // your default barStyle;
  i++;
});
```

If you have an id for each car, better, you can avoid to use **i**.
then, in template:

```
<mat-card [ngClass]="barStyle[i]" *ngFor="let card of obs; let i = index | async | paginate: { id: 'paginator', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: currentPage, totalItems: totalItems }" (click)="highlightCard(i)">
```

I see you use async function in template. So, in ts, you expect and **Observable**. To update style of each card, you need to subscribe at your service and update objects. So, need to do some changes:

**cards: Observable** will become **cards: Card[]**;

**loadingData = true;**

call the service as:

```
getData() {
    this.loadingData = true;
    service().subscribe(cards => {
    cards.forEach(card => {
        this.barStyle[card.id] = // your default barStyle;
        this.cards = cards;
        this.loadingData = false; // this is set false only after data is loaded
    });
}

highlightCard(id: number) {
    if (this.barStyle[id] === 'card') {
      this.barStyle[id] = 'cardHighlight';
    } else {
      this.barStyle[id] = 'card';
    }
  }
```

in template:

```
  <mat-card ***ngIf="!loadingData"** 
     [ngClass]="barStyle[card.id]" 
     *ngFor="let card of obs | async | 
        paginate: { id: 'paginator', 
                    itemsPerPage: 10, 
                    currentPage: currentPage, 
                    totalItems: totalItems }" 
     (click)="highlightCard(card.id)">
```

Somethimes, your template will render before to load data, so you need to use a boolean to wait for it.

**To keep clean code, for pagination you can use a variable initialized in .ts*